# How to order an array of diffrent Dates by Weekday in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have an array with lots of different Dates in Swift and I need to order them by Weekday (or even better split them each into a new array, one with all dates for Monday Tuesday ...) 
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want this week's Monday to be in a different array from next week's or last week's Monday? In other words, do you not care about which week that date is in?

Comment: Do you mean order by or group by weekday? maybe add a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about which week the dates are in and *only* the days of the week, you can use `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` to turn the array of dates into a `[Int: [Date]]`:

```
func weekDay(of date: Date) -> Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date)
}
let weekDays = Dictionary(grouping: dates, by: weekDay)
print(weekDays)
```

For example, `weekDays[7]` will give you all the dates that are on a Saturday, or `nil` if there is no dates on Saturday.

Comment: Wow that's amazing, thank you so much! I was thinking way to Complicated

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the weekday for each day:

```
let dates: [Date] = ...
let datesWithWeekday: [(date: Date, weekday: Int)] = dates.map {
   let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: $0)
   return (date: $0, weekday: weekday)
}
```

Then you can do anything you want with it:

```
var datesPerWeekday: [Int: [Date]] = [:]
for (date, weekday) in datesWithWeekday {
    datesPerWeekday[weekday, default: []].append(date)
}
```